# Eliminating IF statement from this code

Tags: c, if-statement, dry

I have this C function which basically takes the input from the user and saves it in a `static char[]`. Then it checks whether it is empty. If it is empty then it prints an error, else appends a file extension to it. Here's the piece of code I'm concerned about:

```c
const char* text_entry(){
    char c;
    while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF);
    static char input[20];
    fgets(input, sizeof(input),stdin);
    input[strcspn(input,"\n")]=0;
    if(strlen(input)>0){
        strncat(input, ".txt",4);
        return input;
    }
    printf("Error! no text entered!");
    return NULL;
}
```

My concern is that I want to remove the IF statement from it, making it more DRY. How can I do that?

Comment: The `if` is needed to check the input.  Nothing is being repeated here.

Comment: How do you read the user input, your design look very poor. e.g: global.

Comment: @Stargateur the method to read user input is not the point of concern here.

Comment: @dbush the return statement is being repeated; also I want to remove the branch which the IF statement is creating

Comment: @Adnan Well, you are obviously an expert so I think you right.

Comment: @Adnan You can either repeat the `return`, or you can repeat assigning to a result variable.  The former is more concise.  And again, you can't get rid of the `if` because you need to check the user input and return something different based on it.

Comment: The 'create `static char[]` called `input`' part of the comment is opaque; there are many ways to do what you describe, and some of them will lead to trouble.  How did you actually do it?  It's a whole lot easier to help you if you provide an MCVE ([MCVE]), rather than a dismbowelled snippet that cannot be compiled to show the trouble

Comment: "DRY" stands for "don't repeat yourself". I don't see how this applies to your code. I'd be more concerned about the lack of bounds checking. What will happen if `strlen(input)` is less than 5 bytes from the end of the memory area allocated to `input`?

Comment: Ok wait I'll add the implementation of getting user input

Comment: The way you get input does seem of interest; how do you know that `input` is a string? If the input is read into `input` with `fgets()`, `strlen(input)` will always be greater than zero unless code removes the newline. Point is, you _may_ get a better answer if you provide more information.

Comment: Why do you discard the first non-newline character that the user enters?  Why don't you check that the string entered is short enough to leave space for the `.txt` suffix?

Comment: Well,you are effectively doing three passes over the same string. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The `char c` is made to actually flush the `stdin` of any newline character from before. The function `text_entry` is executed when user enter a choice to do so from `main`. I didn't want to show the implementation detail of the user input because it may lead the question away from my main objective.

Comment: @wildplasser is there a way I can do all the three operations in a single pass?

Comment: Urgh…this is rather messy.  It would probably be better to use line- based input ([`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX 
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)) and avoid the need to gobble the residue of previous input in this code.  However, that's a detail, I guess.  You do need to check that there's enough room for the data.  Note that using `static char input[20];` doesn't take much to leave the newline or other data in the input buffer — leaving you with the 'gobbling to newline' problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The `fgets()` includes the newline character in the variable itself, that's why I used the `strcspn()` command to remove the newline character. Using `fgets()` in the `main()` will surely remove the need to "gobble the residue new line" from here

Comment: If there are no characters in the input stream when `text_entry()` is called, the loop that cleans the input stream will block, waiting for input from the user. Is there a previous I/O function that guarantees that there is at least one newline character for `getchar()` to read at this point?

Comment: Yes, `fgets()` includes the newline when the line of text is shorter than 19 characters.  If I type `profit-report-20170706` as the name, though, you aren't going to get the newline.  The `strcspn()` doesn't cause trouble; the appending does.  Note that `strncat()` is a dangerous function.  You can't really use it safely unless you know enough about the arguments not to need to use it at all (you can use `memmove()` or `memcpy()` instead).

Comment: @DavidBowling yes, in the `main`, the user is asked to enter a number and depending on which number he enters, he's taken to different functions, and `text_entry` is one of them. I can't use `fgets` in the `main` with `int` because it messes up the `switch()`'s functionality.

Comment: _"I can't use `fgets()` … because it messes up the `switch`'s functionality"_ — that sounds like a whole separate design issue (flaw).

Comment: @Adnan : the idea is: measuring the string length only once,and reusing that length. The answer by ensc comes close, the  usage of srcspn() is nice.(but he uses an indicator variable and a chained if+else, which I both dont like)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I actually tried `fgets` in `main`, and unless I explicitly remove the newline, the `switch` code crashes the program. But adding more lines mean more complex code, which I don't want to add. I should look into the `memmove` or `memcopy` now.

@wildplasser

Comment: Since we can't see what you're describing, we can't help.  I'll stand by "the code is bug-laden" if using `fgets()` causes it to crash.  If you need help on that part, provide a (crashing) MCVE in a new question to get the problem resolved.

Comment: Yeah, that's a different issue, the `main` and `fgets` relation. That's why I was refraining from inserting the code for user data input. I am mainly concerned about the possible elimination of `if` from this function, by some clever workaround that I can't think of.

Answer (score 1):

The "DRY" is in the usage of `strcspn()`, `strlen()` and `strncat()`.  You can avoid them by

```
size_t l = strcspn(input, "\n");
bool ok = false;

if (l == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: too short\n");
} else if (l > sizeof input - sizeof(".txt")) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: too long\n");
} else {
    strcpy(input + l, ".txt");
    ok = true;
}

return ok ? input : NULL;
```

Comment: Using this code, when I enter a string of maximum length of `input`, it doesn't show any error, it rather "eats" the last character, and place ".txt" in the end.

Comment: @Adnan I can not reproduce this; "0123456789abcde" returns 0123456789abcde.txt" , "0123456789abcdef" fails.

Comment: What is the size of the `input[]` in your code? I used 5, and when I enter `abcd` it works perfectly, but when I enter `abcde` or `abcdef` I get `abcd.txt`

Comment: @Adnan I used `[20]` from your example. `[5]` returns always the "too long" error.  Yet smaller sizes will aloow overflows; when this is really possible in your program, you should catch this by `_Static_assert(sizeof input > sizeof ".txt", "...");` or a runtime check.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *minimal loop* version. It *does*check* if the result fits into the  input buffer.

Note:I'm **not** saying this is the best way todo it. But it avoids multiple scans over the input. (the gain in performance is mostly futile...)

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* text_entry(){
    int ch;
    size_t pos;
    static char input[20];

        //this is dubious: it consumes characters upto and including the first '\n'
    while((ch=getchar())!='\n' && ch!=EOF) {;}

    for (pos=0; pos < sizeof input; pos++) {
        ch=getchar();
        if (ch =='\n' || ch==EOF) break;
        input[pos] = ch;
        }
        // noinput
    if(!pos) return NULL;


        // input too large: cannot append suffix
    if(pos + sizeof ".txt" > sizeof input) return NULL;
    memcpy(input+pos, ".txt", sizeof ".txt" );
    // fprintf(stderr, "[%zu]\n",strlen(input));
    return input;
}

int main(void)
{
char *result;

while(1) {
        result = text_entry();
        if (!result) continue;
        printf("%s\n", result);
        }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: why C89 style... I will never understand we are in 2017.

Comment: What do you want? VLAs ;-?

Comment: My only guess is he is confusing your need for `pos` after the loop complete with you not using `for (size_t pos=0; ...` -- but he will have to elaborate.

Comment: That was the whole idea of the exercise!: looping once. So the`pos` **has to persist** after the loop.(and the OP will have to explain the usage of sizeof ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I did not shorten your code, but I think you might find this solution more resilient, using the libreadline `-lreadline`

Before your returned a buffer which was declared on the stack, which means that it is unallocated on return, but yet you return its address. This is a bug.

I fixed it and gave you the opportunity to take a buffer and buffer size in parameters, as well as the extension, so the caller manages the memory for you as well as his maximum string length needs.

The loop now handles maximum input size well. It might not be shorter, but it should prove resilient.

```
/*
** Args:
** input_buffer: a buffer that will be whiped then filled with the user input
** buffer_size: the total size of the input buffer (maximum result length)
** extension: a dotted file type extension
**
** Returns: 0 on error or the input_buffer
*/
const char* text_entry(char *buffer, size_t buffer_size, char *extension) {
  int maxsize = buffer_size - strlen(extension) - 1;
  char *user_input;
  int user_input_len;

  do {
    user_input = readline("Enter a file name: ");
    user_input_len = strlen(user_input);
    if (user_input_len > maxsize) {
      printf("The name is too long! %d characters maximum. Try again.\n", maxsize);
      free(user_input);
    }
  } while (!user_input_len || user_input_len > maxsize);
  strcpy(buffer, user_input);
  free(user_input);
  strcat(buffer, extension);
  printf("%s\n", buffer); 
  return buffer;
}
```